# webbrowser при обновлении страницы занимает больше оперативной памяти

Tags: delphi, webbrowser, memory

Имеется форма VCL, на ней кнопка и браузер, после каждого просмотра видео память увеличивается на 10-15 мб, у кого какие есть идеи на этот счёт? В гугле это не решенный вопрос.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
WebBrowser1.Stop;
WebBrowser1.DestroyComponents;
WebBrowser1:=TWebBrowser.Create(Form1);
TWinControl(WebBrowser1).Parent:=Form1;
WebBrowser1.Width:=406;
WebBrowser1.Height:=231;
WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.youtube.com/++++++++++');
end;
```

Comment: Не хватает `WebBrowser1.Free`

Comment: пробовал и с ним, нажимаю на кнопку, грузится видео и прирост на 10-15 мб в оперативную память

Comment: Удалите WebBrowser методом `WebBrowser1.Free` и подождите 15 минут. Память должна вернуться системе

Comment: Рост памяти - это нормально. Вы же не видите, сколько сейчас в действительности используется приложением под реальные нужды, а сколько просто отнято у системы (т.е. когда-то это было нужно под какой-либо объект, а потом объект освободили, но память себе оставили). Вот если есть документально подтвержденные утечки памяти - тогда да, надо бить тревогу.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не надо на каждый чих удалять браузер. Это ресурсоемкий объект, его инициализация занимает не так уж и мало. Ну и фрагментацию памяти надо не забывать.

Comment: @kami Вы невнимательны. Я не предлагаю на каждый чих удалять браузер. Я предлагаю **проверить** один конкретный тест

Comment: @AntonShchyrov. Принято :)

Comment: Друзья, а как же быть, моё приложение основано на том чтобы смотреть несколько видео, после каждого просмотра я чищу память IE и закрываю сессию, после чего снова создаю Webbrowser  и загружаю новое видео. Я заметил, что после 50-80 просмотров видео моя программа использует 800 мб оперативной памяти, после виснет.
 ?

Comment: @Zavet может стоит попробовать не удалять WebBrowser? Он уж точно спроектирован так, что бы можно очень долго ходить по страницам.

Comment: @Zergatul      изначально я так и использовал webbrowser, когда увидел, что появились проблемы с памятью стал искать способы их решения, по логике и советам в гугле решил разрушать webbrowser, но это тоже не помогло .

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, сбросил настройки IE по умолчанию.